# Linked List Output not generated correctly

Tags: java, linked-list

StackOverflowers.

I am quite new to this site and thought it wise to come on here for some help regarding a particular problem that involves printing the correct output from a linked list.
The idea was to take a program that used an array to generate a list and convert it into a linked list, whilst achieving the same result. Now, I've been going at this for hours and even though I got to the point where output is actually printed (finally), the required result was not obtained.

Require result:
Note: This result is produced with use of an Array

Word:                 this  count:   2
Word:               course  count:   2
Word:             examines  count:   1
Word:                  the  count:   7
Word:         construction  count:   1
Word:                   of  count:   9
Word:           algorithms  count:   4
Word:                  and  count:   9

Result I am obtaining:
Note: This result is produced when converting array approach into a linked list

Word:               belief  count:   2
Word:                   my  count:   2
Word:                   of  count:   2
Word:                 best  count:   2
Word:                  the  count:   2
Word:                   to  count:   2
Word:                  are  count:   2
Word:                facts  count:   2
Word:                  the  count:   2

I am not exactly sure why this is the case and I cannot seem to track it. I've tried reading over my notes and searching, but to no avail. I am not sure if it has something to do with setNext(...) [part of the Node class] or where I am calling the incrementCount() method [part of the Word class]. I do not believe that setNext(...) even has a purpose, but is just part of the code and doing nothing at all at this point.

I am hoping that my delivery is not off track and that a solution can be provided for my attempt. I know that I've reached my limit because I cannot think of anything else with regards to this.

Looking forward to your suggestions.

Thanks.

T3.

```
private Node top;

public WordList()
{
   top = null;
}

    // This method adds words to the linked list.
public void addWord( String w )
{       
   Word word = new Word( w );
   top = new Node(word,top);

       // Checks to see if a particular word is present more than once.
       // If the particular word is encountered more than once, it 
       // increments the word count for that particular word, else
       // a new node is created to store another word. The word check
       // process is repeated once more.
       // Note: getWord() is part of the Node class that attempts to retrieve
       // a word that is held in a particular node.
       // matchesWord(...) determines whether a particular word (string) has been 
       // encountered. If result is true, the number of times
       // the word is encountered should be incremented. 
   if( top.getWord().matchesWord( w ))
   {
      top.getWord().incrementCount();
   }
   else
   {
      Word newWord = new Word ( w );
      Node newNode = new Node(newWord, top);    
      //top = newNode;
      top.setNext(newNode);
   }
} // end addWord

    // This method prints out the linked list.
public void printList()
{
    Node currentNode;

    currentNode = top.getNext();
    while(currentNode != null)
    {
        System.out.println(currentNode.getWord());
        currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems I can see straight away:

- Unless the `getWord()` method does something rather strange, it will only increment the count if the **very first word** matches the newly-added word
- You are adding a new `Node` to the head of the list regardless of whether there is a match - combined with the first problem results in your counts of 2 for everything
- In `printList()`, you need to start at `top` not `top.getNext()`

Comment: getWord() only returns a word object that's stored in the Node. That's all it does. I attempted to fix the printList() method, but still cannot solve the error.

Comment: Did you understand what I said about always adding a `Node` every time `addWord()` is called? Take that line out, and try iterating your list for matches instead of just checking what's at `top`

Comment: I am grateful for your help, but seeing that I am not progressing, I will just bid you thanks and leave the problem as it is. :-) I tried my hardest. It was an honor to have received your answer.